# Question on Finding Torque Using Cross Product

Tags: vectors

Let r equal the line segment OP=i-j+2k. A force F=<10,10,0> is applied at P. Find the torque O produced.

In calculus we learned that torque is equal to the cross product of the force vector and the radius (arm). However I am having the feeling that in this situation, the answer may not be as simple.

Can anyone confirm or refute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by definition $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$

Assuming $i,j,k$ are the unity vectors specifying the Cartesian coordinates, then:

\begin{equation}
 \vec{r} \times \vec{F} = \begin{vmatrix}
i && j && k \\
1 && -1 && 2 \\
F_x && F_y && F_z \\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
i && j && k \\
1 && -1 && 2 \\
10 && 10 && 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}  = (-20,20,20)
\end{equation}

Comment: Do I have to do anything like find a direction sin or cos?

Comment: wait, now it makes sense with the j. I am, updating it

Comment: Just realized, that is a linear combination of the OP vector.

Comment: You will not need to explicitly find a direction using trig. When you take the cross product, you should get a vector that naturally has a direction.

Comment: @fireballs so the answer is just OPxF?

Comment: @ArnoldFrenzy that's it?? Just take the cross product OPxF??